# Commutative Subrings of Finite  Matrix Rings

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $R$ be a finite commutative ring with identity. Considere the matrix ring $A=M_n(R)$.   What is the order of a maximal commutative subring of $A$ that contains all  scalar matrices?

Comment: That's not true over a field with $n=2$, because there are matrix algebras of rank two over a field, like the ring of diagonal matricies, but $2$ is not less than $1+1$.

Comment: @OP: What is the $R$-dimension of an $R$-algebra if $R$ is no field? This can be a serious problem for arbitrary commutative rings, for instance: Take $R=\mathbb C[x_i:i\in \mathbb N]$ (polynomial ring in infinitely many variables), and take $I$ to be the ideal generated by all $x_i$ ($I$ isn't finitely generated). Then `$\left\{\left(\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\ 0&a\end{array}\right)\mid a \in R, b \in I\right\}$` is a subalgebra of $M_2(R)$ which is neither free nor finitely generated. What dimension would you assign to it?

Comment: Yes, I mean free as an $R$- module. 

Comment: I think that a non-free subalgebra is never maximal, because is contained in a free algebra. For example in the example of Florian Eisele if we take $b\in R$ (and not in the ideal I) the subring is free. 

Comment: No, if $R=\mathbb Z/4$ then in the algebra of $2\times 2$ matrices there is a maximal commutative algebra consisting of the matrices that are scalar plus even.

Comment: well, we must impose restrictions on the ring $R$. If $R$ is finite maximal subrings mean subring of maximal order. If $R$ is infinite suppose that $R$ is a principal ideal domain. 

Comment: @zacarias: If $R$ is a PID, then you can just tensor your maximal subalgebra of $M_n(R)$ with the quotient field $K$ of $R$ to get a subalgbera of $M_n(K)$. This shows that in this case the same bounds as for fields apply. The case of a finite $R$ could be interesting, though. 

Comment: Yes, the interesting problem is for finite rings. 

Comment: @Zacarias: you should then edit your question to make it meaningful, which is not the case at the moment.